# Adding String to this in jQuery

Tags: jquery

If **this** is an HTMLDivElement, how do I avoid doing this ?

```
$('#' + $(this).id + " > p").foo();
```

to do something like :

```
($(this) + $( " > p")).foo();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$(this).children('p').foo();
```

Comment: I was hoping to concatenate more in the string, but for this children would do.

Comment: You can use `.find` to select any descendants matching a selector, if you don't want direct children.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(this).find("> p").foo();
```